# How to target sibling of parent with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a button that I want to have enact changes to an element that is the sibling of the button's parent.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="target"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <button>Click!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried playing around with `event.target.closest` and similar, like so, but I cannot get it to work:

```
function clicks(event) {
    const childElement = event.target.closest(".child");
    const parentElement = childElement.target.closest(".parent");
    const targetElement = parentElement.target.closest(".target");
    
    targetElement.style.display = "none";
}

addEventListener('click', clicks);
```

[Vizualisation of intention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0BJz.png)

Comment: Your final call to `.closest()` is not going to work as you think, "The closest() method of the Element interface traverses the element and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the specified CSS selector" - [Element.closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), it's moving up the DOM tree looking for the child element of the `parent`, you could do `parentElement.querySelector('div.target');`

Comment: `event.currentTarget.closest(".parent").querySelector(".target")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parentNode property to get the parent element of the button, and then use the nextElementSibling property to get the target element:

```js
function clicks(event) {
    const parentElement = event.target.parentNode;
    const targetElement = parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    
    targetElement.style.display = "none";
}

addEventListener('click', clicks);
```

Comment: I doubt this is going to work. How is .child going to have the next sibling when it is the last element?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments section, you can't use `.closest` as it moves up the DOM tree and you are trying to get a child of the parent in your final call to `.closest`, one option is to use `querySelector` on the parent element like so, also on your second line of function `clicks`, the `childElement` variable does not have
a `target` property so it produces `undefined` when setting `parentElement`:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', clicks);
});

function clicks(event) {
    const childElement = event.target.closest("div.child");
    //const parentElement = childElement.target.closest(".parent");
    const parentElement = childElement.closest("div.parent");
    //Don't use .closest()
    //const targetElement = parentElement.target.closest(".target");
    const targetElement = parentElement.querySelector('div.target');
    targetElement.style.display = "none";

    //You could reduce all this to one line:
    //event.target.closest('div.parent').querySelector('div.target').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="target">I am the target</div>
  <div class="child">
    <button>Click!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Documentation:** [Element.closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the two properties - parent and previousElementSibling for this.

This simple example finds the button's parent then finds the sibling that is just before it:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.classList.add('nextClicked');
});
```

```css
.nextClicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">Parent
  <div class="target">Target</div>
  <div class="child">Child
    <button>Click!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```